# Load view in views folder. $this->loadTemplate from new folder

Tags: joomla3.8

To load parts of currently opened view I use default template part loading function `$this->loadTemplate`. `$this->loadTemplate('default_cover');`

But for easier view management I want to put different view parts in different folders.

In this case I would like to know if it's possible to select folder from which to load required view with $this->loadTemplate function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's view's `addTemplatePath()` to add additional lookup paths:

```
$this->addTemplatePath(JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_example/templates/example_view');
```

With this, the custom path is prioritized, meaning it would override template overrides in standard folders. To reverse that, reverse the array order of `$_path['template']`:

```
$this->_path['template'] = array_reverse($this->_path['template']);
```

Or, instead of using `addTemplatePath()`, manually add the path:

```
$this->_path['template'][] = JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_example/templates/example_view';
```

Also, if you want to allow custom structure in template overrides, add template folder too (also mind the lookup order):

```
$this->addTemplatePath(JPATH_THEMES . '/' . JFactory::getTemplate() . '/html/com_example/example_view');
```

p.s. I don't endorse using custom folder structure. This only leads to confusion for users trying to make overrides. Perhaps look into using layouts instead?

Comment: Wow. That's great explanation. Thank you @Sharky
Yeah. It seems a bit too confusing